# ¿Es posible que un API en .NET 5 pueda ser accesible desde HTTP y no por HTTPS?

Tags: c#, api, http, https, net

Tengo la necesidad (y en cierta parte la curiosidad) de saber si es posible consumir endpoints por http y no por https desde un api C# .NET. ya que si le mando `https://localhost:44338/api/Person` me trae datos, pero si lo mando `http://localhost:44338/api/Person` no me devuelve nada.

¿Como puedo hacer que traiga desde HTTP y no por HTTPS?

Gracias

Comment: Si la API no expone un endpoint para `http` entonces no puedes consumirla con ese protocolo directamente. La API es tuya? Si es tuya puedes modificarla para que permita comunicarse usando ambos protocolos, pero tal vez no sea lo más aconsejable. Si no tiene habilitado `http` por algo será. Saludos

Comment: Yo creo que el problema es el puerto. No puede ser 44338 para https y también para http. Tienen que usar puertos distintos obligatoriamente. Busca cual es el puerto de http y yo creo que debería funcionar sin problema. Ahora bien, lo de que sea un api sin proteger .... espero que solo sean pruebas.

Comment: vale gracias, si solo era pruebas y la verdad era por que tenia la duda, jamás dejaría un api sin HTTPS